# How to query a List of Group of T

Tags: c#

I have follow classes.

```
public class City
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
    }
```

.

```
public class Group<T> : List<T>
    {
        public Group(string name, IEnumerable<T> items)
            : base(items)
        {
            this.Title = name;
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

In my constructor of my class (`myViewModel`) i do something like this

```
cityList = new List<City>();
cityList.Add(new City() { Name = "Milan", Country = "IT", Language = "Italian" });
cityList.Add(new City() { Name = "Roma", Country = "IT", Language = "Italian" });
cityList.Add(new City() { Name = "Madrid", Country = "ES", Language = "Spanish" });
```

Now, I expose a property called  `DataList` as shown below which creates an Group of list country wise. Hence, DataList.Count = 2

```
public List<Group<City>> DataList
        {
            get
            {
                _datalist = GetCityGroups();
                return _datalist;
            }
        }

public static List<Group<City>> GetCityGroups()
        {
            IEnumerable<City> cityList = GetCityList();
            return GetItemGroups(cityList, c => c.Country);
        }

        private static List<Group<T>> GetItemGroups<T>(IEnumerable<T> itemList, Func<T, string> getKeyFunc)
        {
            IEnumerable<Group<T>> groupList = from item in itemList
                                              group item by getKeyFunc(item) into g
                                              orderby g.Key
                                              select new Group<T>(g.Key, g);

            return groupList.ToList();
        }
```

Now, for a given Name (say Milan) , I need to find to which Group (DataList[0] or DataList[1]) does it belong.  How do i do it ?

I want to avoid hardcoding as shown below

```
Group<City> g = vm.DataList[0]; // remove this hardcoded 0 here...
City c = g.FindLast(x => x.Name == "Milan");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vm.DataList.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Any(x => x.Name == "Milan"))
```